# Summation of matrices involving eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Help me please to understand the formula:

Let **A** be a $m\times m$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Consider the singular value decomposition of **A**, **A**=**U**$\Lambda$**U**$^{T}$. Here, the columns of **U** are orthonormal vectors. $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, $\Lambda$=diag([$\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{m}$]) with 0$\leq\lambda_{i}\leq1\forall i$. Without loss of generality, suppose $\lambda_{1}\geq\lambda_{2}\geq...\geq\lambda_{m}$. We have

**A**=**U**$\Lambda$**U**$^{T}$=$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}$**u**$_{i}$**u**$_{i}^{T}$=$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{i+1})$   $(\sum_{j=1}^{i}$**u**$_{j}$**u**$_{j}^{T})$+$\lambda_{m}$$(\sum_{j=1}^{m}$**u**$_{j}$**u**$_{j}^{T})$.

I don't understand how to get the right hand side?

Comment: Try looking up the rank one decomposition of a matrix.  That explains the $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \textbf{u}_i \textbf{u}_i^T$ term.  Also, in what you wrote above you need to change the $a_i$ to $\lambda_i$.

Comment: If you mean the second equality, it's an ordinary telescoping trick. Just compare terms on both sides for a fixed $i$.